# Data Validation between spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check whether a row from one table in one spreadsheet contains the same values for certain columns in another row in a table in a separate spreadsheet. This is going to be used for data validation.

For instance, I need to confirm that the item in row 2 of **Table 1** has the same PO Number and Date of the item with the same Item Number (row 2) in **Table 2**.

I have included a link to an image containing the sample tables:

[image]

What is the best approach in tackling this problem? This is a simple representation because there are typically over 200 rows to be validated.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: So what is your ultimate goal. After validating, what do you need to do? This can be done in some ways depending on how your data is set-up.

Comment: Using SQL in excel macro will solve your problem, something i would like to know is : what are you going to do if the PO Number and Date are same/ not the same?

Comment: Yes, you need to say something about after conditions is True of False. This problem can solve by using SQL or Just checking with looping. So, you should say more. Ok?